# How to make a boolean variable turn true when called in a main method //Java

Tags: java

---

I am making a superHero class where methods are called when Attack the attack method is called, but how can I make the current false boolean switch to true once the method is called?
My code:

```
Random random = new Random();
double rand = random.nextDouble();
boolean att = false;
public double attack(double AttackDam, double Health, double Stamina, double BlockChance)
{
    do
    {
        if(BlockChance == 0.0)
        {
            Health = Health - AttackDam;
        }
        else
        {
            AttackDam = AttackDam - BlockChance;
            Health = Health - AttackDam%BlockChance;
            Stamina = Stamina - AttackDam%BlockChance;
        }
        att = false;
    }while(att == true);

    return Health;
}
```

Comment: `}while(att = true);` not again... even if it would be some pseudocode you should either use `==` or skip `==true` part ( `while(att)` is perfectly fine, actually it is even preferred). Right now you are creating infinite loop because `att` will always be reset to `true` (`=` is assignment, not comparison).

Comment: Sorry,high school programmer. haha

Comment: do you know what a while loop does?

Comment: What you have above doesn't loop regardless of your `att` boolean. As coded above you could completely remove `att` and it would have the same affect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random random = new Random();
double rand = random.nextDouble();
boolean att = false;
public double attack(double AttackDam, double Health, double Stamina, double BlockChance)
{
            att = true;
    do
    {
        if(BlockChance == 0.0)
        {
            Health = Health - AttackDam;
        }
        else
        {
            AttackDam = AttackDam - BlockChance;
            Health = Health - AttackDam%BlockChance;
            Stamina = Stamina - AttackDam%BlockChance;
        }

    }while(att == true);
    return Health;
}
```

But where are you setting att to false, to break free from the `do...while` loop?

Comment: won't work. The code that sets att to false has to be inside of the loop otherwise the loop will never be broken.

Comment: If that is the case then you don't need the do...while

Comment: Would a while loop suffice?

Comment: You don't need it because you don't need a loop. You don't need a do...while; you don't need a while ...., or any for-loop.

Comment: Can you add more information about what this is doing?

Comment: @user3754559 do you know what a while loop is supposed to do? I recommend you take an intro to programming course or read an entry level book, before you start trying to write a program.

Answer (score 0):

From what I am understanding, you want the "att" boolean to be made true when the attack method is called. This will then trigger the following code to calculate the health to return.

If that is correct, then each time the method is called you want to calculate the health to return one time, and one time only, therefore you do not require a loop. I believe what you think you are looping for is something like

```
    boolean var;
    do{
        var = true;

        // some code

        var = false;
    }while(var);
```

But, when your last line in your loop sets the loop condition (the boolean) to false, it ensures that the loop will never loop back to the top and run again. Therefore it's the equivalent of just doing:

```
    boolean var;
    var = true;

    // some code

    var = false;
```

What you should instead be doing, is calculating how many times you would like to call the "attack" function, and loop that many times calling it. An example would be something like the following, I used a "main" function to call the attack function, but that could be substituted anywhere

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    int numberOfTimesToAttack = 2;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfTimesToAttack; i++){
        attack(10.0,500.0,5.0,5.0);
    }

}
```

And then the attack function would be:

```
public double attack(double AttackDam, double Health, double Stamina, double BlockChance)
{
    if (BlockChance == 0.0) {
        Health = Health - AttackDam;
    } else {
        AttackDam = AttackDam - BlockChance;
        Health = Health - AttackDam % BlockChance;
        Stamina = Stamina - AttackDam % BlockChance;
    }
    return Health;
}
```

Try to think of each function as a part of an assembly line. Each one is broken into it's own job, and only does that small job, it doesn't worry about the job of anyone else. The attack function has one purpose, to simulate the attack. It shouldn't calculate how many times that the attack must be performed, this is a different function.